# Roll a fair 6−sided die until a 6 appears.Given that the first 6 occurs before the first 5, find the expected number of times the die was rolled

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve this problem but my answer is coming out to be 1.5 where the answer is 3. I even ran a simulation to verify it and its correct. I am not really sure whats wrong in my method and how can I correct it.

I considered for getting my first 6 on Nth trials, without any 5's till now, I have probability of
$$P(A^N) = \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{N-1} \times \frac{1}{6}$$

Now to get the expected number of rolls,

$$\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} N \times \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{N-1} \times \frac{1}{6}$$

So, If we bring **1/6** outside, and consider **x = 4/6** then the above equation is the 1st derivative of **x/(1-x)**

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{x}{1 - x} \right) = \frac{1}{{(1 - x)}^2}$$

Putting back the values and multiplying by 1/6 we get 1.5 (9/6). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: For the conditional probability you need to divide by the probability that the conditioning event occured.

Comment: @lulu can you please explain it a bit more. I understand that you are suggesting to use P(A/B), using that my P(A/B) was coming (4/5)^(N-1). The formula that I have used above is P(A ^ B) , where A = 5 hasnt occured N-1 trials and B = 6 has occured on the Nth Trial

Comment: The conditional probability that $A$ happens given $B$ is $\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.  You correctly analyzed the numerator, but you neglected the denominator, which is $\frac 12$ by symmetry.

Comment: You might find [this](https://www.yichijin.com/files/elchanan.pdf) relevant.  It concerns a different problem, but the ideas are similar.  Famously unintuitive.  Note that, in the discussion on the "right way" to reduce the sample space, the method used is (presumably) exactly what your simulator did....generate a bunch of sequences and throw out the ones that failed the conditioning test.

Comment: Addendum to the comment of lulu: you have found the probabilities that the trial will end in $N$-th round and 6 comes before 5. But it is *given* that 6 comes before 5.

Comment: The expected number of rolls until the first $5$ or $6$ is three. The situation between $5$ and $6$ is symmetric. The cases where $6$ comes ahead of $5$ will mirror those where $5$ comes ahead of $6$. You are given $6$ comes before $5$. That takes half the cases out, but doesn't change the expected number of throws.

Answer (score 1):

> Roll a fair 6−sided die until a 6 appears.Given that the first 6 occurs before the first 5, find the expected number of times the die was rolled

Let $N$ be the number of rolls until you stop, and $\mathcal C$ be the condition.

- $(1/6)$ is the probability for rolling a `6` (which is not a `5`, of course).
- $(4/6)$ is the probability for rolling neither a `5` nor a `6`.
- $(4/6)^{n-1}(1/6)$ is the probability for never rolling a `5` *and* the first `6` being on roll `n`.  IE:  $\mathsf P(N{\,=\,}n\cap\mathcal C)$
- Thus $\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n(4/6)^{n-1}(1/6)}$ is the expected count of rolls until the first `6` **and** we never roll a `5` before stopping.

  - This is $\mathsf E(N\mathbf 1_\mathcal C)$.  Yes this is $1.5$, but this is not what we wanted to calculate.
  - We actually want $\mathsf E(N\mid\mathcal C)$, the conditional expectation of the count for rolls until we stop on a `6` *when given* that we never rolled a `5` before stopping.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(N\mid\mathcal C) &= \dfrac{\mathsf E(N\mathbf 1_\mathcal C)}{\mathsf P(\mathcal C)} \\[1ex]&= \dfrac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n (4/6)^{n-1}(1/6)}{1/2}\\[1ex] &= 3\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrived at 1/2 as the denominator? Is that the probability of never rolling a 5 in n trials?

Comment: @alexandrosangeli $\mathcal C$ is the event that the first $6$ occurs before the first $5$.  The complement is that the first $5$ happens before the first $6$. Thusly: $\mathsf P(\mathcal C)=\mathsf P(\mathcal C^\complement) = 1/2$.

Comment: Or by the hard way $\mathsf P(\mathcal C) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (4/6)^{n-1}(1/6) = 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it that we can mix expected outcomes and probabilities in Bayes' theorem? That is, why is it possible that we can divide E(N1_c) by the probability of event C?

Comment: @alexandrosangeli It comes from the *definition* of conditioning expectation over a non-zero-measure event.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(N\mid\mathcal C) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n~\mathsf P(N=n\mid\mathcal C) \\ &=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\dfrac{\mathsf P(N=n\cap \mathcal C) }{ \mathsf P(\mathcal C) } \\ &= \dfrac{\mathsf E(N~\mathbf 1_{\mathcal C})}{\mathsf P(\mathcal C)}\end{align} $$

Comment: Thank you, @GrahamKemp!