# Invalid Conditional Probability - Expectation of Die Rolls

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability

Problem: [Roll a fair 6−sided die until a 6 appears.Given that the first 6 occurs before the first 5, find the expected number of times the die was rolled](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797583/).
Note: A discussion on the solution already exists in the following link, but that doesn't discuss this alternative approach.

Correct solution using arithmetic-geometric progressions:
$E = \sum_{i=0}^\infty(4/6)^i*(2/6)*(i+1)$,
$E = \sum_{i=0}^\infty(2/3)^i*(1/3)*(i+1)$,
$E = 3$.
Here, $2/3$ is the probability of a throw resulting in a non-terminating number $i.e., 1, 2, 3, or, 4$. If a throw yields $5, or, 6$, we stop. From symmetry, the arrived value of expectation is also our answer.

Argument: Given that $5$ did not occur, since the die is fair, it should be deducible that the probability of occurrence of each of $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and, $6$, should be $1/5$.
Solving for $E$:
$E = \sum_{i=0}^\infty(4/5)^i*(1/5)*(i+1)$,
$E = 5$.

The answer is understandably $E = 3$. What exactly is wrong with the above argument, and why? (Which mathematical rule/property is violated?)

Also, consider the following:
Given a fair 6-sided die, what is the probability of a throw yielding $1$ if it is known that the throw did not yield $5$?
The answer is trivially $1/5$; and is the same for the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and, $6$.
How does the conditional probability of $5$ not occurring fit this example, but not the main problem?

Comment: As mentioned in the question you link to, you need to be careful as to how you restrict the sample space.  [this paper](https://www.yichijin.com/files/elchanan.pdf) (also linked to in that other question), addresses the problem with the approach you propose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Argument: Given that $5$ did not occur, since the die is fair, it should be deducible that the probability of occurrence of each of $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and, $6$, should be $1/5$.
>
> Solving for $E$:
> $${E = \sum_{i=0}^\infty(4/5)^i\cdot(1/5)\cdot(i+1)\\E = 5}$$

This is the expected count of rolls *which do not show $\it 5$* until the first $6$ shows.

Not counting any rolls showing $5$ is not the same as conditioning on *the first $\it 5$ occurring after* the first $6$.