# What is the expected number of rolls of a fair 6 sided die given that you roll a 6 before you roll a 5?

Tags: probability

I know that the answer to this is 3 as I understand the approach used in the solution however, I was trying to solve this by using the equation:
$$
e = \frac{4}{6}(e+1) + \frac{1}{6}
$$

where $e$ denotes the expected value that we are trying to calculate.
This gives $e=2.5$.  What is wrong with the logic I used here ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797583/roll-a-fair-6%E2%88%92sided-die-until-a-6-appears-given-that-the-first-6-occurs-before-t).  I don't understand the calculation you provided.

Comment: Here's a trick. Let $E$ be the expected number of rolls. Notice that the probability that I roll a $6$ in the first roll given that I roll a $6$ before a $5$ is $1/3$ using the conditional probability formula. The probability I do not roll a $6$ is then $2/3$. So $E$ must satisfy the recursive formula $E = (2/3)(E+1) + 1/3$. Solve this to get $E = 3$.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thanks @User203940